# Не меняется формат даты GsonBuilder

Tags: android, retrofit2, gson, simpledateformat

Пытаюсь изменить формат даты, которую получаю через запрос API. Использую GsonBuilser. Как я понимаю, при изменении параметров в setDateFormat("")
формат должен меняться. 
Но при любых изменениях выдает результат: 2008-01-12T07:51:46Z

Как мне добиться отображения нормальной даты? Возможно даже просто даты, без времени? 
Спасибо! Код ниже

```
Gson gsonDate = new GsonBuilder()
            //.setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
            .setDateFormat(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT)
            .create();

    Retrofit retrofitDate = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gsonDate)).build();
    GitHubUser gitHubUserDate = retrofitDate.create(GitHubUser.class);

    Call<PojoGitUser> callDate = gitHubUserDate.getUserInfo(login);
    callDate.enqueue(new Callback<PojoGitUser>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<PojoGitUser> call, Response<PojoGitUser> response) {
            PojoGitUser infoDate = response.body();
            tvDate.setText("Bio: " + infoDate.getCreatedAt());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<PojoGitUser> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}

public interface GitHubUser {
    @GET("users/{username}")
    Call<PojoGitUser> getUserInfo(@Path("username") String login);
}
```

Comment: Какой тип у Вас возвращает метод `infoDate.getCreatedAt()`? Настройка `setDateFormat` влияет на конвертацию полей типа `java.util.Date, java.sql.Timestamp` и `java.sql.Date` в json и обратно, но не на вывод их на экран.

Comment: похоже что строку. 
 public String getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }
не понимаю, что с этим делать. можно как то тип изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дата которая приходит от апи `"2018-10-27T06:34:39+00:00"`

Вот так:

```
private String getFormattedDate(String rawDate) {
    SimpleDateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(RESPONSE_FORMAT, Locale.ROOT);
    SimpleDateFormat displayedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(MY_FORMAT, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        Date date = utcFormat.parse(rawDate);
        return displayedFormat.format(date);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

И запрашиваю в адаптере:

```
String my_date = getFormattedDate(newsPojoList.get(position).getPublishedAt());
```

где `getPublishedAt()` геттер который возвращает дату из `JSON` : `"2018-10-27T06:34:39+00:00"`